# Knex with Postgres storing timestamp in unintended ways

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I am using Knex query builder with Postgres in my application. I am trying to add a `created_at` and `updated_at` fields in my database with ISO8016 formatted data in UTC time. I am trying to have my data look like this:

```
2017-04-20T16:33:56.774Z
```

In my Knex migrations, I have tried using both the `.timestamps()` method creating both `created_at` and `updated_at` manually with the `.timestamp()`
 method and naming them myself.

When I seed my database and set `created_at` and `updated_at` equal to `moment().utc().toISOString()`, but it stores in my database as this:

```
2017-04-20 11:20:00.851-05
```

There is something between the code and the database changing the data and I don't know if it's Knex, the Postgres Node library, or Postgres itself.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres stores timestamp in internal format and when you read it it shows it in the format that you request it.

```
knex_test=# update accounts set created_at = '2017-04-20T16:33:56.774Z';                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  UPDATE 47
knex_test=# select created_at from accounts where id = 3;
         created_at         
----------------------------
 2017-04-20 19:33:56.774+03
(1 row)

knex_test=# \d accounts
                                       Table "public.accounts"
   Column   |           Type           |                          Modifiers                          
------------+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id         | bigint                   | not null default nextval('test_table_one_id_seq'::regclass)
 last_name  | character varying(255)   | 
 email      | character varying(255)   | 
 logins     | integer                  | default 1
 about      | text                     | 
 created_at | timestamp with time zone | 
 updated_at | timestamp with time zone | 
 phone      | character varying(255)   | 
Indexes:
    "test_table_one_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "test_table_one_email_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (email)
    "test_table_one_logins_index" btree (logins)

knex_test=#
```

You can change in which timezone postgres returns timestamps for your connection with

```
knex_test=# SET timezone = 'UTC';
SET
knex_test=# select created_at from accounts where id = 3;
         created_at         
----------------------------
 2017-04-20 16:33:56.774+00
(1 row)

knex_test=#
```

And here is how its done with knex https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/97

```
var knex = Knex.initialize({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: {
    host     : '127.0.0.1',
    user     : 'your_database_user',
    password : 'your_database_password',
    database : 'myapp_test',
  },
  pool: {
    afterCreate: function(connection, callback) {
      connection.query('SET timezone = timezone;', function(err) {
        callback(err, connection);
      });
    }
 }
});
```

Comment: I have been playing with this and setting the timezone against the actual database as you described works great, but trying to do it programmatically with the `afterCreate` function as you've described does not run on my migrations and seeds. Is there a way to force that to run or check if that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I got it running on my migrations and seeds, but I still don't have the appropriate timezone. I will keep trying at it.

Comment: You should be able to make that query as a first query in transaction and then all the queries after that in the same transaction should have the correct time zone. Also that setting doesn't affect at all how data is stored / read inside postgres, so you shouldn't need to set it in migrations.